# Removing duplicate rows and printing only the latest rows in a file using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

The format of my file looks like this:

```
3313513003|481206309|3008296|2111|20150218000000|20150218000000|100|200|
3313513003|481206309|3008296|2111|20150218000000|20150219000000|000|010|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20150217000000|20150317000000|000|000|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20150217000000|20150317000000|000|010|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20141219000000|20150118000000|200|000|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20141219000000|20150118000000|200|010|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20141105000000|20141205000000|200|010|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20141105000000|20141205000000|200|000|
```

The script should delete multiple records present in the file, the criteria is as follow:

1.For the same $1,$2,$3,$4 there are multiple records present in the file. We need to remove the multiple records and print only the latest two records.

2.The latest records will be identified by comparing $6 among the records which have the same $1,$2,$3,$4.

3.There will be two records which the same value of $6 but have different value in $7,$8. We need to print these.

The output file should like as mentioned below:

```
3313513003|481206309|3008296|2111|20150218000000|20150218000000|100|200|
3313513003|481206309|3008296|2111|20150218000000|20150219000000|000|010|
There are no multiple records for this case.
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20150217000000|20150317000000|000|000|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20150217000000|20150317000000|000|010|
The 6 records present in the File are compressed into 2 for this case.
```

Comment: Is there REALLY a blank line between lines 2 and 3 of your input file? If not, get rid of it. And if those are the ONLY output lines you expect then clarify why.

Comment: Are you missing a field or is field 9 empty? Your example has 4 different values of $5 so I guess the output should show all the lines.

Comment: The latest records: Do you mean the date/time represented by $5 ($6?) or the order in the file?

Comment: @WalterA, sorry, I have removed $5, we need to check based on $1,$2,$3,$4. These will be common.

Comment: Is the file sorted (allowed to be sorted)? We would want to use a `while IFS="|" read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8`, remember the last f1-4 and the $f6, and print when we have another f1|f2|f3|f4

Comment: @EdMorton,I have removed the blank line. As for the result ..

Comment: @EdMorton,

The code will read the first line $1,$2,$3,$4 `3313513003|481206309|3008296|2111` and since this $1,$2,$3,$4 will be unique there will no need to compare $6 in this case.It will print the entire row.

Now the code will read the second line 
`3313513003|481206309|3008296|2111` and in this case since $6 is not equal to the $6 of the last case, it will print this line aswell.

The code will read the third line the logic that will be applied to it will be the same as that of the first line, same is the case with the fourth line the logic applied will be the same as that of the 2nd line

Comment: Now it will read the fifth line and when it will see that the $1$2$3$4 have already occurred it will compare $6 to the old record and since in this case it is less than $6 of the old records it will discard this record.

Comment: Please note that for $1$2$3$4 there will be two rows with same value in $6 but different or same in $7 and $8, the goal is to print the latest two records.

`3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20150217000000|20150317000000|000|000|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20150217000000|20150317000000|000|010|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20141219000000|20150118000000|200|000|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20141219000000|20150118000000|200|010|`
in the above example, the last two rows should be printed whereas the above two should be deleted

Comment: Define what you mean by `latest`. And please edit your question to include all of the corrections and additional information from your comments and then delete the comments.

Comment: @WalterA, yes we can sort the file! :)

Comment: Please include the code you have used so far to solve your problem. Stackoverflow isn't about free coding services. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't think I understand the logic you want to apply but based on what I THINK I know about your requirements this would be the right approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "|" }
{ key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 }
key != prevKey || $6 == prev6
{ prevKey = key; prev6 = $6 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
3313513003|481206309|3008296|2111|20150218000000|20150218000000|100|200|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20150217000000|20150317000000|000|000|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20150217000000|20150317000000|000|010|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20141219000000|20150118000000|200|010|
3313513000|481206306|4610335|47498|20141105000000|20141205000000|200|000|
```

hopefully you can work it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of your question could be answered by

```
cut -d"|" -f1-4 yourfile | sort -u | while read key; do
   grep "^${key}" yourfile | sort -t"|" -u -k6,6 | tail -2
done
```